# GPS Jumping all over the place on iOS

Tags: ios, geolocation, titanium, titanium-mobile

I've got a geolocation handler which deals with my GPS locations and sends them to a PHP service. This works perfectly fine on Android and is easily followed on a google maps web-app i made. However; I've tested it on an iPhone 4s and 4 and the coordinates jump all over the place. Following perhaps Wifi spots closeby or even the network provider towers. How is it possible that iOS jumps like a toddler on sugar and Android works fine? I've tried it with PROVIDER_GPS and without the preferredProvider and with and without Wifi enabled.
Here's my location handling:

```
Ti.Geolocation.purpose = 'Determine Current Location';
Ti.Geolocation.preferredProvider = Ti.Geolocation.PROVIDER_GPS;
var callback;
function locationHandler(e) {
    if (e.success === undefined || e.success) {
        if (typeof (callback) === 'function') {
            callback(e);
        }
    }
} 
function start(obj) {
    callback = obj.action;
    Ti.Geolocation.addEventListener("location", locationHandler);
}

function stop() {
    callback = undefined;
    Ti.Geolocation.removeEventListener("location", locationHandler);
}

exports.start = start;
exports.stop = stop;
```

Comment: I'm afraid the ultimate *performance* of your location app on iOS has little to do with its performance on Android.  Two separate kinds of phones, with different location services implementations.  Are both phones on the same carrier?  Can you tell us which geographic region, and which Android phones you're comparing?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by geographic region. I've used several Android phones(Older and new ones) And 2 iPhone's. 4 and 4s. All Androids do exactly the same and show a very nice line through the streets.(Tested for a few hours straight). The iPhone follows the same path however has very strange jumps in between it. Exact spot -> 200 meters north -> exact spot in mere seconds. I'm assuming it's a wifi/g spot(haha!) it found and jumps on it. Look at my screenshot of the 2 tracks(Pocketed both phones and walked with it at the same time): http://www.envyum.nl/tracked.png

Comment: "Geographic region" means "where were you?".  It looks like somewhere in the Netherlands? A city?  Were there tall buildings?  A good view of the sky?

Comment: In one of the capitals yes. Deadcenter in it. Tall buildings; Not very closeby no...

Comment: Please notice that iPhones don't have a GPS sensor. Their position is located via A-GPS  and Wifi (and GLONASS in Russia). You may set [accuracy](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Geolocation-property-accuracy) to best for iOS.

Comment: I've set accuracy_best which made a slight difference. So iOS never picks up GPS 'out of the sky' sort of speak? Unless there's no reception from networks...

Comment: iOS doesn't have GPS. it has only assisted GPS (calculated from cellular networks) and wifi.

Comment: And there's no way to filter out the jumpiness somehow?

Comment: That could be a cell tower it's jumping to, it doesn't need to be a WiFi hotspot. And mr.VVoo is incorrect, the phone does have a GPS receiver, it just "assists" it with cell and wi-fi location for quicker locates. http://www.macworld.com/article/1159528/how_iphone_location_works.html